# Python: number guessing with elimination

Tags: python

```
from sys import setrecursionlimit
from random import randint
from time import perf_counter


time = perf_counter()


def calc(b):
    if a > b:
        print(b, " is too low")
        enter(b, d)
    elif b > a:
        print(b, "is too high")
        enter(c, b)
    elif a == b:
        print("Right", a, " = ", b)
        print(time)


def enter(x, y):
    calc(randint(x, y))


# qwe
setrecursionlimit(100000000)
m = int(input("Number: "))
a = randint(1, m)
c = 1
d = m

enter(c, d)
```

If I enter 200, its going to guess until it gets the number that was chosen.
And basically the sole reason I made this post, is that I want to make it keep guessing in between what is possible and what not. If the number was 100 and the machine guessed 150, 150 would be too much and every number would be eliminated after 150. This is done by having `randint()`, the second expression a.k.a. `y` be 150. But when it guesses again and this time it does 90, it would guess between 90 and 200 because I've never saved the number 150. Question is, how do I save the 150 so that it can eliminate everything after 150? Or 90 if it comes to that?

## In case anyone wants to know, here is the code that works https://pastebin.com/Bu2FD6mt

Comment: You keep generating random numbers because `calc` calls `enter` which calls `calc` again but with a new `randint`

Comment: Also you don't even need recursion. You can have `while True` inside `calc`, and `break` in case the guess is correct

Comment: Yeah, I do have to generate random numbers because otherwise how is it going to guess? @DeepSpace also, for the second one. I dont understand, I am new to Python. I wouldn't need ```break``` because if it guesses right the script just ends.

Comment: use Stackless Python and don't worry about stack limit is also an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, don't use recursion. Use `while True` and `break` out of it in case there is no need for more guesses.

Putting aside all the "bad single-letter-variable-names", this works:

```
from random import randint

def calc(b):
    while True:
        if a == b:
            print("Right", a, " = ", b)
            break
        if a > b:
            print(b, " is too low")
        elif a < b:
            print(b, "is too high")
        b = randint(c, d)

def enter(x, y):
    calc(randint(x, y))

m = int(input("Number: "))
a = randint(1, m)
c = 1
d = m

enter(c, d)
```

Comment: This is great, but hasn't really teached me anything, how does the ```while True:``` and ```break``` help me here?

Comment: @DanielMer the `while True` indefinitely compares `a` to `b`. If they are equal, the `break` will terminate the loop. If they are not equal, `b` will be a new random number and the loop continues. That's the simplest way I can explain that.

Comment: Okay, this is great, now, do you have a solution for my other problem maybe? The one about narrowing the random number generated?

Answer (score 0):

You may make 2 lists: 1 for values too low, 1 for too high.
and check `randint()` if it is too high or too low by using `for` loop with range of the length of the list.If you don't know `for`,use`while`.  `while` is easier to understand.

Comment: A list? Wouldnt it just skip the values in the list instead of skipping the above or below it?